# how to create disable UIButton in swift?

Tags: swift

I have func checkstatus with 2 operands:

```
func  checkstatus (atept: Float, made: Float, labelcheck:UITextField){

    if (atept > made) {
        labelcheck.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        calculate.enabled = false
        calculate.alpha=0.66
    }else
    {
        calculate.enabled = true
        calculate.alpha=1

    }
}
```

then this func call 3 times. But if I have false false after first or second calls of this func my button (calculate) still enable.

called in:

```
@IBAction func che(sender: AnyObject) {
    var made1pt = (made1ptShots.text as NSString).floatValue
    var made2pt = (made2ptShots.text as NSString).floatValue
    var made3pt = (made3ptShots.text as NSString).floatValue

    var att1pt = (attempt1ptShots.text as NSString).floatValue
    var att2pt = (attempt2ptShots.text as NSString).floatValue
    var att3pt = (attempt3ptShots.text as NSString).floatValue

    checkTrueStats(made1pt, made: att1pt, labelcheck:made1ptShots)
    checkTrueStats(made2pt, made: att2pt, labelcheck:made2ptShots)
    checkTrueStats(made3pt, made: att3pt, labelcheck:made3ptShots)


}
```

botton must disable when one or more func = false. But it's work when last called = false. 
Maybe need add && or || ?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! Could you give us an example of the situation this function will be called in?

Comment: I can't reproduce your error: this code works, the error must come from elsewhere.

Comment: add code where function called in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add contructoin

```
  if (
     (checkTrueStats(att1pt, made: made1pt, labelStats: made1ptShots) ) && (checkTrueStats(att2pt, made: made2pt, labelStats: made2ptShots)) && (checkTrueStats(att3pt, made: made3pt, labelStats: made3ptShots))
    ) {
```